# Query running in developer console but not through Force client in .Net

Tags: soql, relationships, developer-console, .net, subquery

Following query runs fine in developer console and workbench but fails in .Net code which uses Force Rest client:

```
Select  Id, Name, (select contact.id, contact.firstname FROM account.contacts), (Select Id, Name, Street__c, City__c, Zip__c, State__c, Country__c From Locations__r) From Account
```

Error I am getting is:

> ERROR at Row:1:Column:153
> Didn't understand relationship 'Locations__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Location object has a reference field Account__c pointing to Account.

This is first I am seeing that a query is running in dev console but not in .Net's force client. Is it related to configuration?

Thanks in anticipation!

Regards,
Haris

Comment: Are you authenticated to Salesforce as the same user in both clients?

Comment: yes I am using same user in both .net code and developer console.